# NowPlayable with AudioKit Observation of Values

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, audiokit

I am currently in the midst of changing my audio engine from an `AVQueuePlayer` to `AudioKit`. I setup my 'NowPlayable' Lock Screen player using this [example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/becoming_a_now_playable_app) from Apple.

I am having trouble changing the below code to work with my `AKClipPlayer`. How do I observe the below items using AudioKit?

```
// Private observers of notifications and property changes.

private var itemObserver: NSKeyValueObservation!
private var rateObserver: NSKeyValueObservation!
private var statusObserver: NSObjectProtocol!

// Observe changes to the current item and playback rate.

itemObserver = player.observe(\.currentItem, options: .initial) {
    [unowned self] _, _ in
    self.handlePlayerItemChange()
}

rateObserver = player.observe(\.rate, options: .initial) {
    [unowned self] _, _ in
    self.handlePlaybackChange()
}

statusObserver = player.observe(\.currentItem?.status, options: .initial) {
    [unowned self] _, _ in
    self.handlePlaybackChange()
}
```